# Seeking to modify code to pull data from an excel sheet where column A has X numeric value. ( ie all rows with value= 0 )

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Just to be upfront, I am a Mechanical Engineer with limited coding experience thou I have some programming classes under my belt( Java, C++, and lisp)
I have inherited this code from my predecessor and am just trying to make it work for what I'm doing with it. I need to iterate through an excel file that has column A values of 0, 1, 2, and 3 (in the code below this correlates to "Revs" ) but I need to pick out all the value = 0 and put into a separate folder, and again for value = 2, etc.. Thank you for bearing with me, I appreciate any help I can get

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import os.path
import xlsxwriter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import six
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator, MultipleLocator
def CamAnalyzer(entryName):
    #Enter excel data from file as a dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel (str(file_loc) + str(entryName), header = 1) #header 1 to get correct header row
    print (df)
    
    #setup grid for plots
    plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17,22))
    gs = GridSpec(3,2, figure=fig)
    props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='w', alpha=1)

    #create a list of 4 smaller dataframes by splitting df when the rev count changes and name them
    dfSplit = list(df.groupby("Revs"))
    names = ["Air Vent","Inlet","Diaphram","Outlet"]

    for x, y in enumerate(dfSplit):
        #for each smaller dataframe #x,(df-y), create a polar plot and assign it to a space in the grid
        dfs = y[1]
        r = dfs["Measurement"].str.strip(" in") #radius measurement column has units. ditch em
        r = r.apply(pd.to_numeric) + zero/2 #convert all values in the frame to a float
        theta = dfs["Rads"]
        
        if x<2:
            ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,x],polar = True)
        else:
            ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[2,x-2],polar = True)

        ax.set_rlim(0,0.1) #set limits to radial axis
        ax.plot(theta, r)
        ax.grid(True)
        ax.set_title(names[x]) #nametag

    #create another subplot in the grid that overlays all 4 smaller dataframes on one plot
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,:],polar = True)
    ax2.set_rlim(0,0.1)
    for x, y in enumerate(dfSplit):
        dfs = y[1]
        r = dfs["Measurement"].str.strip(" in")
        r = r.apply(pd.to_numeric) + zero/2
        theta = dfs["Rads"]
        ax2.plot(theta, r)
        
    ax2.set_title("Sample " + str(entryName).strip(".xlsx") + " Overlayed")
    ax2.legend(names,bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.05)) #place legend outside of plot area
    plt.savefig(str(file_loc) + "/Results/" + str(entryName).strip(".xlsx") + ".png")    
    print("Results Saved")
```

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? You say "I need to pick out all the value = 0 and put into a separate folder" --> you need to write a bunch of zeroes into a file in another folder? Or you need to copy that set of excel rows into another spreadsheet, saved in a different folder?

Comment: What I mean is I have an excel file with columns A1= revs B1=step C1=time for every rev value of 0 I would like to copy the entire ROW to another Excel file and do this for revs 0, 1, 2, 3. my data set only goes up to rev= 3 I was thinking because I usually have around 300 for each rev count and I just want to separate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on my phone, so I can't check exact code examples, but this should get you started.

First, most of the code you posted is about graphing, and therefore not useful for your needs. The basic approach: use pandas (a library), to read in the Excel sheet, use the pandas function 'groupby' to split that sheet by 'Revs', then iterate through each Rev, and use pandas again to write back to a file. Copying the relevant sections from above:

```
#this brings in the necessary library
import pandas as pd

#Read excel data from file as a dataframe
#header should point to the row that describes your columns. The first row is row 0.
df = pd.read_excel("filename.xlsx", header = 1)

#create a list of 4 smaller dataframes using GroupBy.
#This returns a 'GroupBy' object.
dfSplit = df.groupby("Revs")

#iterate through the groupby object, saving each
#iterating over key (name) and value (dataframes)
#use the name to build a filename
for name, frame in dfSplit:
    frame.to_excel("Rev "+str(name)+".xlsx")
```

Edit: I had a chance to test this code, and it should now work. This will depend a little on your actual file (eg, which row is your header row).

Comment: When I plug this in and run it with the correct input file it complies and runs but doesn't create any files

Comment: Check where the files are being created: the working directory for your python. See, for example, https://linuxize.com/post/python-get-change-current-working-directory/

Comment: That was it. Than you very much!

Comment: Great! If you want to, go ahead and 'accept' the answer (there's a little check mark to click on).